# dotnet resources dll, replace a string (lost source code)

Tags: .net, dll

I've lost the source code to a dotnet 3.5 dll which holds all my strings (html documents) and images. I now need to update one of those documents and some of the images. What's the best way for me to update the strings in the file (they will be different lengths, will that matter?)

Answer (score 3):

## Step #1: Disassemble the assembly.

Use the following command to disassemble your .net exe or dll:

```
ildasm /out=assembly_name.il assembly_name.dll
```

(replace assembly_name.dll with your dll or exe name).

This will output plenty of data files. We are interested in these:

- *.resources - The binary resource files.
- assembly_name.res - The resources manifest.
- assembly_name.il - The actual MSIL code.

## Step #2: Edit the resources file(s).

Prepare the modified/new resource, it doesn’t matter what name it is but the format should be the same as the one originally included in the assembly (e.g. replacing bitmap for bitmap, icon for icon).

Use a resource editor to edit the resource file. I use Resourcer for DotNet (http://www.aisto.com/roeder/dotnet/) by Lutz Roeder, it’s freeware. By the way, the same author also wrote Reflector.NET, an awesome tool for .NET developers.

If you’re using the Resourcer, here are the steps required:

- Open the .resources file you want to change and rename the original resource item.
- Hit Ctrl-F to insert file and select the modified version from you file system.
- Rename the new item to have the same original name as the previous one (you can’t you copy/paste for that, for some reason it just copies the entire item instead of just the text).

## Step #3: Reassemble the assembly.

Use the following command to disassemble your .net exe or dll:

Important: This will overwrite the original dll/exe !

```
ilasm /resource=assembly_name.res /dll /output=assembly_name.dll /key=signing_key.snk assembly_name.il
```

(replace assembly_name.dll with your dll or exe name and of course change the /dll to /exe if needed).

The signing key parameter is optional and is only needed if the original assembly was signed.

Of course, if it was signed by someone else to prevent tempering, you won’t be able to use the modified assembly unless you provide the original signing key, which I assume you won’t have. But that’s just how .NET works.

Answer (score 1):

Directly editing a compiled assembly is sketchy.  I would decompile it with a [decompiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) back into source and fix it proper.  Put it back into source control, too.

Comment: [Sketchy](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sketchy) basically means that you either shouldn't be doing it or that it is too difficult to get done correctly in a reasonable amount of time. My point is: don't try and edit the binary assemblies; decompile them into source that you then can use normally.  Normally-ish.

Comment: I'm evaluating whether it is going to be easier to take this age old dll from the dawn of dotnet and just edit the one little thing that needs to change and save it again - or go through the process of having to build it again from scratch (which is what most decompilers I've looked at require me to do - they show me the code, but I have to build it all again manually). Which costs money.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that it's easier to

EDIT THE DLL WITH A HEX EDITOR

than it is to START OVER which is the usual advice.